# VB to C# Code Translator

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I am convering VB code to c#:

```
Private Function SoundsLike(ByVal pWord As String, 
             Optional ByRef pAccuracy As Byte = 6) As String.
```

But I got different type of parameters. Let me know how can I write in C#.

Comment: Use online conversion tool to perform this [Online code language conversion tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)

Comment: Download VB.NET to C# convertor from [VB.NET to C#](http://dw.com.com/redir?edId=3&siteId=4&oId=3000-2212_4-10635897&ontId=2212_4&spi=03ea29c759b6dd915ae646642484f122&lop=link&tag=tdw_dltext&ltype=dl_dlnow&pid=12217602&mfgId=6256772&merId=6256772&pguid=T7SnJAoOYJUAAH686HEAAAKv&ttag=dl_dldirect&destUrl=http://download.cnet.com/3001-2212_4-10635897.html?spi=03ea29c759b6dd915ae646642484f122&dlm=0)

Comment: If you prefer online, you can use http://converter.telerik.com/ or http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 5):

VB.Net

```
Private Function SoundsLike(ByVal pWord As String, Optional ByRef pAccuracy As Byte = 6) As String
```

C#

```
private string SoundsLike(string pWord, byte pAccuracy = 6)
{
}

private string SoundsLike(string pWord, out byte pAccuracy)
{
}
```

Note that `out` and `ref` cant have a default values

FYI : "The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. This is similar to the ref keyword, except that ref requires that the variable be initialized before being passed." 
Reference: http://geekswithblogs.net/ftom/archive/2008/09/10/c-and-the-difference-between-out-and-ref.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The code like the following:

```
private string SoundsLike(string pWord, byte pAccuracy = 6);
```

requires C# 4.0 because contains optional parameters. For earlier version the same can be achieved via overload.

Comment: wasn't there when you first added your answer.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: Passing byte by ref makes no sense to me.

Comment: @abatishchev The high-school yearbook photo pose kills me, dude. Nice job.

Comment: @Yatrix: Awesome comment, dude. Was waiting it for years :D

Comment: @abatishchev Some ppl just don't understand real genius, man. I do. =)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
private string SoundsLike(string pWord, byte pAccuracy = 6)
```

**OR just**

```
 private string SoundsLike(string pWord, out byte pAccuracy)
```

`Private` is optional. If no modifier given, default is `Private`

```
void abc(){}
```

is same as

```
private void abc() {}
```

Same with variables.

Comment: `ref` cannot have a default value

Comment: Also, don't ever leave the modifier off. It's bad practice.